# Graph API error retrieving Sharepoint childrens in runtime but not during tests

Tags: c#, sharepoint, graph

I'm working with Graph to syncronize a folder with a remote Sharepoint drive, .NET 8.0, Graph library version 5.41.0
To obtain the childrens of the root of the drive I'm using this chunk of code

```
DriveItem rootFolder = graphClient.Drives[_localSettings.driveId].Root.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
 {
     requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "children" };
 }).Result;
```

and it works while I debug it in VS, in fact my software works quite fine if I execute it directly from VS, BUT when I compile it, arrived here it gives me "One or more errors occurred. "Property Get method was not found." exception.
Why? This is driving me mad

I do not understand why it works just fine when I test the code in VS but returns the error when I compile and execute it

Answer (score 0):

You could use following code to list childrens

```
// Code snippets are only available for the latest version. Current version is 6.x

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

com.microsoft.graph.models.termstore.TermCollectionResponse result = graphClient.sites().bySiteId("{site-id}").termStore().sets().bySetId("{set-id}").children().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it seems it was a bug in the library. I've updated GraphClient component and everything works fine now.
Thanks for the help